# Tool to refactor "with" blocks

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-2007, with-statement

Is there a refactoring tool to remove "with" blocks? For example convert

```
with Form1 do
begin
  Height := Blah;
  Blubb := Name;
end;
```

to

```
Form1.Height := Blah;
Blubb := Form1.Name;
```

where Form1 is a VCL TForm. Optimally it should work with Delphi 2007.

Comment: I don't think there's something like this, it requires a lot of parsing that needs to go down to a TObject decendant in order to achieve this...

Comment: From the fact that neither MMX nor the built-in Delphi refactoring seem to contain it I figured that the problem probably is harder than other refactorings. Bummer. :-)

Comment: As a sidenote: The difficulty in implementing that refactoring is exactly the reason why `with` can be dangerous!

Comment: @Smasher, as the compiler can resolve the with, so should do a refactoring. The result might not be what you expect.

Comment: @Smasher: There is no such difficulty.  The code compiles and does what it is directed to do.  Any refactoring simply needs to reproduce the scoping rules that the compiler follows.  The "dangers" you are thinking of stem from the fact that the debugger doesn't follow these rules properly itself when it comes to "with".  "with" would be less of a problem (tho not entirely benign) if the debugger worked properly.

Comment: @Deltics: "simply needs to reproduce the scoping rules"...that's exactly what I mean. That's what you have to do in your head also and it can get quite tricky and complex.

Comment: @Smasher I do not think so. It can really be what 'we do not expect' as Uwe said. But that's exactly why we need refactoring the `with`! I've always thought that the `with` is not a problem for the compiler but for the programmer who think understand how it works.

Comment: @Smasher - the point is, yes it's difficult but that is no impediment to creating a reliable "with refactoring".    The rules that the refactoring has to follow don't have to be deduced, they are already written and embodied in the compiler.  Presumably the devs working on the debugger code similarly just gave up and said "Yes, we could fix it but it's too difficult.  Oh woe how it sucks to be us.".  Yet somehow the compiler team managed, as evidenced by the fact that the compiler, um, does it.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

...I think the last Castalia from Jacob Thurman/TwoDesk Software do the trick

Answer (score 13):

One of the [Castalia refactoring tools](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/delphi-refactoring.html) is named "Eliminate 'WITH'".

I can't comment on how well it works in non trivial code because I tend to avoid "with".

Comment: ... and because you were faster :)

Comment: +1 of course. I accepted User0815's answer to support the SO newbies. :-)

Comment: I can live with that.  The other answer is equally correct and just two minutes behind mine.

Comment: The other answer has no link, so I accepted yours :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Model Maker Code Explorer](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/), which became free recently, has "Convert with statement" tool. While it is not a fully automated refactoring, it might be useful, if Castalia does not work

Comment: After I read your answer, I just tried it. It didn't really help much. In all tests the automatically generated code didn't compile and it was faster to do the conversion by hand.

Comment: @dummzeuch, I found it most useful for huge (tens of lines) withs. It has several options, which might make removal easier.
However, it is still a simple text tool, not a refactoring, and it's a matter of taste, so I will not insist.